# JavaScript simple regular expression - limit string to have exactly '#' as first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I basically want to parse a string such as:

```
"#FFFFFF"   to "#FFFFFF",
"##FFFFFF"  to "#FFFFFF",
"FFFFFF"    to "#FFFFFF"
```

I'm having issues making a generic regex expression that will handle cases like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wow - so many insanely complex solutions to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str =  '###FFFF';
str = str.replace (/^#*/, '#')
```

Replaces 0 or more occurrences of # at the start of the string with a single #

Answer (score 1):

You want something like `/^[#][^#]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatThing(string){
    return "#" + string.replace(/#/g,"");
}
```

Replace all '#' with nothing, and stick a '#' on the front. In my opinion this is more readable than any convoluted regex. It works for all three of the inputs provided, as well as a few other odd cases.

Mind you, this is for *converting* as your question suggested you wanted, not matching. Better if you're trying to normalize different inputs, in that X to Y sense you wrote in the question.  Taking "##FFFFFF" and *matching* all except the first "#", or refusing to match "FFFFFF" because it lacks a leading "#" wouldn't suffice here right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to match any number of # OR then anything in the beginning.  Like so (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUGE8/)):

```
new RegExp("(^#+|^)");

// #Test -> #Test
// ####Test -> #Test
// Test -> #Test
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the "g" modifier.

Comment: True, there should only ever be one of these since he wants it starting at the beginning of the string. I'm fixing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace any (or none) of the `#` characters at the beginning with a single instance of `#`:

```
resultString = sourceString.replace(/^#*/, "#");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "#fffff";
string = string.replace(/#*/g, function(m, i){ return !i?"#":"";});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not validate that the string is in fact a valid color, but just enforce that the string has exactly one hash as the first character (by stripping all hashes from the string no matter where they are and then adding one at the front):

```
var colorString = "##ffffff";

console.log("#" + colorString.replace(/#/g, "")); // prints #ffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to add to the mix that checks for a 3-6 letter hex code with or without a leading #.

```
var re = /#?([A-F0-9]{3,6})/i;
function getHex (str){
   var val = str.match(re)
   return val ? "#" + val[1] : null;
}

console.log( getHex( "#FFFFFF" ) ); 
console.log( getHex( "##FFFFFF" ) );
console.log( getHex( "FFFFFF" ) );
```